# Webpack "Cannot find module test.scss"

Tags: javascript, docker, webpack, sass-loader

I'm running webpack in a docker container if that makes any difference.

My webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './app/Resources/scripts/test.js',
    output: {
        filename: './web/js/bundle.js'
    },
    watch: true,
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [{
                loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
            }, {
                loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
            }, {
                loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

My test.js:

```
require('../styles/test.scss');
alert('Hello');
```

My file structure:

```
app/
--Resources/
----scripts/
------test.js
----styles/
------test.scss
web/
--js/
----bundle.js
webpack.config.js
```

My dockerfile is:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install curl -y
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash - && apt-get install nodejs -y
RUN npm install webpack sass-loader css-loader style-loader node-sass -g
CMD webpack
```

The JS compiles fine, works etc. However when trying to compile SCSS it fails with the error:

**webpack_require**(!(function webpackMissingModule() { var e = new Error("Cannot find module \"../styles/test.scss\""); e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; throw e; }()));

Comment: Maybe could be a wrong @import or and error inside your .scss file. Another problem could be node-sass, try to run `npm rebuild node-sass` if you have node.js version 6. Check this [github issue](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/240)